# Excel 2010 VBA - using the Like operator to copy cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the contents of a cell only if the cell contains times in the following format: 9:00-5:00pm. (The cell may contain abbreviations such as "N/A", "RDO", "Leave" etc.
I tried this:

```
If Worksheets(2).Cells(R, c).Value Like "*-*" Then

Worksheets(26).Cells(x, c).Value = Worksheets(2).Cells(R, c).Value
end if
```

but it doesn't work properly. I'm experience with VBA in Excel, but I've never used the LIKE operator before.

Answer (score 2):

To look for a `-` only;

```
"*-*"
```

Alternatively you could be stricter;

```
if x like "#*:##-#*:##[ap]m"
```

Comment: It works ok as far as I can see, i doubt it has meaning outside of a [charlist]

Comment: I tested, but I must not have been paying enough attention :(

Answer (score 0):

the `Like` part of your code is fine.  to prove it, run this code fragment:

```
If "9:00-5:00pm" Like "*-*" Then
    MsgBox "True"
End If
```

the problem must lie elsewhere.  post some details of how it doesn't work for you...

Comment: I tested the Like part as you suggested and it worked perfectly.

It turns out I had something else wrong, but I couldn't see it.

Thank you very much for your help.